# JSON Schema - can array / list validation be combined with anyOf?

Tags: visual-studio-code, jsonschema

I have a json document I'm trying to validate with this form:

```
...
"products": [{
    "prop1": "foo",
    "prop2": "bar"
  }, {
    "prop3": "hello",
    "prop4": "world"
  },
...
```

There are multiple different forms an object may take. My schema looks like this:

```
...
"definitions": {
  "products": {
    "type": "array",
    "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/Product" },

  "Product": {
    "type": "object",
    "oneOf": [
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/Product_Type1" },
      { "$ref": "#/definitions/Product_Type2" }, 
      ...
    ]
  },

  "Product_Type1": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "prop1": { "type": "string" },
      "prop2": { "type": "string" }
  },
  "Product_Type2": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "prop3": { "type": "string" },
      "prop4": { "type": "string" }
  }
...
```

On top of this, certain properties of the individual product array objects may be indirected via further usage of `anyOf` or `oneOf`.

I'm running into issues in VSCode using the built-in schema validation where it throws errors for every item in the `products` array that don't match `Product_Type1`.

So it seems the validator latches onto that first `oneOf` it found and won't validate against any of the other types.

I didn't find any limitations to the `oneOf` mechanism on jsonschema.org. And there is no mention of it being used in the page specifically dealing with arrays here: https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html

**Is what I'm attempting possible?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your general approach is fine. Let's take a slightly simpler example to illustrate what's going wrong.

Given this schema

```
{
  "oneOf": [
    { "properties": { "foo": { "type": "integer" } } },
    { "properties": { "bar": { "type": "integer" } } }
  ]
}
```

And this instance

```
{ "foo": 42 }
```

At first glance, this looks like it matches `/oneOf/0` and not `oneOf/1`. It actually matches both schemas, which violates the one-and-only-one constraint imposed by `oneOf` and the `oneOf` fails.

Remember that every keyword in JSON Schema is a constraint. Anything that is not explicitly excluded by the schema is allowed. There is nothing in the `/oneOf/1` schema that says a "foo" property is not allowed. Nor does is say that "foo" is required. It only says that if the instance has a keyword "foo", then it must be an integer.

To fix this, you will need `required` and maybe `additionalProperties` depending on the situation. I show here how you would use `additionalProperties`, but I recommend you don't use it unless you need to because is does have some problematic properties.

```
{
  "oneOf": [
    {
      "properties": { "foo": { "type": "integer" } },
      "required": ["foo"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    },
    {
      "properties": { "bar": { "type": "integer" } },
      "required": ["bar"],
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jason! Your [even more] simplified example cleared up my confusion.

Complicating the matter is that VSCode seems to have a bug in the JSON Schema validation mechanism. I ended up using `ajv-cli` and now I'm seeing exactly the errors I would expect from what you explained.